# laravel sql queries not working after conversion from regular sql

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if you could look at 3 sql queries followed by the converted JOIN queries that do not work. I keep getting an undefined index error - not sure what i'm doing wrong.

**Please note that $db_table_prefix = app_ No big deal.**

**$db->sql_escape = mysql_real_escape_string (removed b/c laravel does it's own escaping)**
1:
OLD:

```
$sql = "SELECT ".$db_table_prefix."Users.Group_ID, 
       ".$db_table_prefix."Groups.* 
       FROM ".$db_table_prefix."Users
       INNER JOIN ".$db_table_prefix."Groups ON ".$db_table_prefix."Users.Group_ID = ".$db_table_prefix."Groups.Group_ID 
       WHERE
       User_ID  = '".$db->sql_escape($this->user_id)."'";
```

NEW:

```
return (array)DB::table('app_Users')
  ->select('app_Users.Group_ID')
  ->join('app_Groups', 'app_Users.Group_ID', '=', 'app_Groups.Group_ID')
  ->where('User_ID', '=', $this->user_id)
  ->first();
```

2:
Old:

```
$sql = "SELECT ".$db_table_prefix."Users.Group_ID, 
        ".$db_table_prefix."Groups.* FROM ".$db_table_prefix."Users 
        INNER JOIN ".$db_table_prefix."Groups ON ".$db_table_prefix."Users.Group_ID = ".$db_table_prefix."Groups.Group_ID
        WHERE User_ID  = '".$db->sql_escape($this->user_id)."'
        AND
        ".$db_table_prefix."Users.Group_ID = '".$db->sql_escape($db->sql_escape($id))."'
        LIMIT 1
        ";
```

New:

```
return (bool)DB::table('app_Users')
  ->select('app_Users.Group_ID')
  ->join('app_Groups', 'app_Users.Group_ID', '=', 'app_Groups.Group_ID')
  ->where('User_ID', '=', $this->user_id)
  ->where('app_Users.Group_ID', '=', $id)
  ->first();
```

3.
Old:

```
$sql = "SELECT ".$db_table_prefix."Users.Group_ID, 
       ".$db_table_prefix."Groups.* 
       FROM ".$db_table_prefix."Users
       INNER JOIN ".$db_table_prefix."Groups ON ".$db_table_prefix."Users.Group_ID = ".$db_table_prefix."Groups.Group_ID 
       WHERE
       User_ID  = '".$db->sql_escape($userId)."'";
```

New:

```
return (array) DB::table('app_Users')
  ->select('app_Users.Group_ID')
  ->join('app_Groups', 'app_Users.Group_ID', '=', 'app_Groups.Group_ID')
  ->where('User_ID', '=', $userId)
  ->first();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you are getting the undefined index from some other code that use returns from the 3 queries you post here. Can you post that code that process the return values as well? It seems like you are trying to access your returned data in the wrong way rather than the queries themselves.

Comment: I was using the queries in a class and called them using $functionvar['Group_Name']. It should work because it returns an array.

Comment: But the array structure could be different from what you expected. Try var_dump it out to check that the returned array matches what you expected yet?